# linux shell - strange 'if'?

Tags: linux, shell

I am reading a source code, and find these lines :

```
if [ -n "${INIT_NAMENODE+1}" ]
then 
    echo "Initializing namenode"
else 
    echo "Starting namenode"
fi
```

how should I interpred the 'if' condition : if [ -n "${INIT_NAMENODE+1}" ] ? ?

Comment: Which bit do you consider strange?

Comment: There is a related post over here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99186

Comment: euh.... the whole condition ... what is the  [ -n ] doing here ?  what is the [+1] here for ? I am a newbie on linux shell I have to say... what are the [ " " ] usefule for here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about this code is that it is not written for a "Linux shell". It is written for the more general category of "UNIX shell". It will work in everything since V7 UNIX (1979) at least. People with lesser portability goals might write it without the `-n`.

The first item of interest is the `${foo+bar}` syntax. This is a test for existence of the `foo` parameter. If `$foo` exists, then `${foo+bar}` equals `bar`. If `$foo` doesn't exist, then `${foo+bar}` equals the empty string.

If you look for this in your shell man page, it's usually documented as `${foo:+bar}`, along with some other related forms like `${foo:-bar}`, and somewhere nearby there's a note explaining that the colon can be omitted from all of them, resulting in slightly different behavior (with the colon, variables whose value is the empty string are treated the same as nonexistent variables).

Next we have the `[ -n ... ]` test. `-n` tests the following string for emptiness. It succeeds if the string is *non-empty*. From the previous paragraph we know that `${INIT_NAMENODE+1}` is empty if and only if `$INIT_NAMENODE` doesn't exist. So the `-n` test succeeds if `$INIT_NAMENODE` exists. The value `1` doesn't really matter here - it would do the same thing if you changed the `1` to `2` or `0` or `teapot`. All that matters is that it's not an empty string, since `-n` doesn't care about the rest.

Try some examples from your shell prompt: `echo ${PATH+hello}` should say `hello` because you do have a `$PATH` variable. `echo ${asdfghjkl+hello}` should print a blank line.

So, in the context of the `if` statement, the purpose of the test is to do the first `echo` if the variable `$INIT_NAMENODE` exists, and the second `echo` if the variable `$INIT_NAMENODE` doesn't exist.